# How to install WPF application to a PC without Framework 3.5

Tags: wpf, frameworks, installation

I have a question about how to deploy WPF application into a PC without Framework 3.5.
If a PC just installs Windows XP and sp3, Is it possible to design a setup package that can install WPF Application directly on this PC?

The situation is like this:

I designed a simple WPF Application. And I want to get its setup package.
When the customs get the package, they can install the application directly, even if their PCs do not have Framework3.5 installed.

Is it possible?
If it is possible, how can I do this?

//-----------------------------------------------------------

I found Matt give a http://forums.microsoft.com/EmbeddedWindows/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3967493&SiteID=47>solution
Is it the only solution?

You can delete .NET assemblies you don't use from the GAC as long as you test your app to make sure that you don't trim down too much. Majority of .NET assemblies are wrappers on top of Win32 API so they can be removed without affecting the OS.

- You can get the list of which assemblies you are using by looking at References node in Visual Studio solution explorer on your development machine. All dependencies are there (If assembly A depends on assembly B, both A and B mist be in the list) but there are some assemblies belonging to the runtime itself such as Accessibility.dll see the list below.
- Make sure you use gacutil.exe (can be called from Visual Studio command prompt) to remove the assemblies. You have to run gacutil after you boot up your embedded image and have .NET installed. Just copy the SDK\v2.0\bin folder from Visual studio
- gacutil.exe /l can be used to list all assemblies installed.
  I used to try to run WPF application on WinPE with no .NET installed. I just manually install the CLR + about 30 dlls from .NET. Here is the list of all files required
  10/19/2006  05:13 PM            10,752 Accessibility.dll
  09/18/2006  01:32 PM            66,728 big5.nlp
  09/18/2006  01:32 PM            82,172 bopomofo.nlp
  11/01/2006  10:34 PM            17,920 Culture.dll
  11/01/2006  10:34 PM             9,728 fusion.dll
  09/18/2006  01:32 PM           116,756 ksc.nlp
  11/01/2006  10:34 PM           326,656 mscorjit.dll
  10/19/2006  05:14 PM         4,366,336 mscorlib.dll
  11/01/2006  10:34 PM           330,752 mscorrc.dll
  11/01/2006  10:34 PM         5,632,512 mscorwks.dll
  09/18/2006  01:32 PM            59,342 normidna.nlp
  09/18/2006  01:32 PM            45,794 normnfc.nlp
  09/18/2006  01:32 PM            39,284 normnfd.nlp
  09/18/2006  01:32 PM            66,384 normnfkc.nlp
  09/18/2006  01:32 PM            60,294 normnfkd.nlp
  09/18/2006  01:32 PM            83,748 prc.nlp
  09/18/2006  01:32 PM            83,748 prcp.nlp
  11/02/2006  04:36 AM         3,915,264 PresentationCore.dll
  02/23/2007  06:06 PM           184,320 PresentationFramework.Aero.dll
  02/23/2007  06:06 PM           126,976 PresentationFramework.Classic.dll
  11/02/2006  04:36 AM         4,972,544 PresentationFramework.dll
  02/23/2007  06:06 PM           376,832 PresentationFramework.Luna.dll
  09/18/2006  01:32 PM           262,148 sortkey.nlp
  09/18/2006  01:32 PM            20,320 sorttbls.nlp
  10/19/2006  05:14 PM           413,696 System.configuration.dll
  10/19/2006  05:14 PM         3,035,136 System.dll
  10/19/2006  05:14 PM           704,512 System.Drawing.dll
  10/19/2006  05:14 PM         5,414,912 System.Windows.Forms.dll
  10/19/2006  05:14 PM         2,039,808 System.XML.dll
  02/23/2007  06:06 PM            32,768 UIAutomationProvider.dll
  02/23/2007  06:06 PM            86,016 UIAutomationTypes.dll
  11/02/2006  04:36 AM         1,167,360 WindowsBase.dll
  09/18/2006  01:33 PM            28,288 xjis.nlp

Hope that helps

Matt

Comment: But now they have a half-assed version of 3.5 installed, and unless they are very restricted machines that will only ever be running your WPF app, you've crippled them. I don't really see the advantage this has over bootstrapping the framework installer into your installer.

Comment: If this works off a USB stick running windows PE, it would definately be useful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 SP1 adds support for the "Client Profile" subset of the .NET Framework. If the Windows XP SP3 machines you're targeting don't have any version of the .NET Framework installed already, this will install a slimmed-down version of the Framework with the assemblies you need for a WPF app. Microsoft provides a bootstrapper installer that will install/update the .NET Framework on the client machine, then chain to your installer to install your application. Here are some links to get started:

- Overview of the [.NET Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Deploying a .NET Framework Client Profile Application by using Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656819.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Deploying a .NET Framework Client Profile Application by using ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656916.aspx)

Comment: The client profile is almost exactly useless for anyone who shipped a .net 2 app, because you have to ship all 250M of .net 3[.5] for your existing customers.  From where I sit, it's a solution to a problem which is almost the one I have, but doesn't help me at all.

Comment: Yes, I can't imagine that it'll be too useful in practice until .NET 4.0 ships. Then (because virtually no one will have it installed already), the Client Profile should make installation a lot slimmer.

Comment: I was successful when using this approach, however, is there a way to make the application appear on the start -> programs menu?

Answer (score 0):

When you use ClickOnce, In your Deploy Option from Project Propertys, set your requireds assemblyes as included, then if you really needs some assemblyes, use gacutil.exe or drag and drop on your client local GAC