# How to include .net framework 4.0 in my setup file while installing it has to go to internet and automatically should download and install the file?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my setup file I want to include .Net Framework 4.0

While installing the setup if my client does not have the .Net Framework 4.0 it has to download from the internet and should install it with the setup file.

How is this done for an application developed in WPF?

Comment: Please do some research before asking. This question is already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579883/add-net-framework-4-0-into-setup-project

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below link, I think it will help you to find the solution:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/631683/Standalone-NET-Framework-exe

[How to install WPF application to a PC without Framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191251/how-to-install-wpf-application-to-a-pc-without-framework-3-5)

[Installing WPF application on machine without .NET Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528126/installing-wpf-application-on-machine-without-net-framework-4)